# how to implement fasthttp framework

Tags: go

I want to start learning about the fasthttps server from this link https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp but I dont know that how will I implement a small piece of code in this framework. Can anybody tell me that how i will implement a small piece of code in this? example please.

Code I tried

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyHandler struct {
    foobar string
}

func main() {

    // pass bound struct method to fasthttp
    myHandler := &MyHandler{
        foobar: "foobar",
    }
    fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8080", myHandler.HandleFastHTTP)

    // pass plain function to fasthttp
    fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8081", fastHTTPHandler)
}

 // request handler in net/http style, i.e. method bound to MyHandler struct.
 func (h *MyHandler) HandleFastHTTP(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
     // notice that we may access MyHandler properties here - see h.foobar.
     fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Hello, world! Requested path is %q. Foobar is %q",
    ctx.Path(), h.foobar)
}

// request handler in fasthttp style, i.e. just plain function.
func fastHTTPHandler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Hi there! RequestURI is %q", ctx.RequestURI())
}
```

Can you please tell me that how I will implement this code.

Comment: So, exactly in which point do you encounter a problem in your try?

Comment: You didn't even import fasthttp.

Comment: If you are new to Go the best advice might be: Just use net/http instead of something special with a very narrow focus. It will suit you better.

Comment: Asking for resources, such as examples, is off-topic here. If you have a specific problem, though, we can probably help with that.

Comment: But first off: Don't use that library. If you're new to Go, first use the standard library's `net/http` package, and become very comfortable with that. Only then, and only if performance is not adequate, should you even begin to consider `fasthttp`.

Answer (score 3):

This code seems to be working. I pasted it to a `.go` file, added:

```
import "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
```

Then you have to install this package, either by using `go get github.com/valyala/fasthttp` or by writing a `go.mod` file if you want to use the new module support.

Then run this file and open `localhost:8080` in a browser.

---

Maybe you have a more concrete question?

As @Volker said in a comment, for newbies it's highly recommended to stick to the standard library - `net/http` in this case; there are *way* more examples and code/tutorials you can find by googling, no need to install special packages, etc.